# R dataframe factors

Tags: r, r-factor, coercion

I want to `droplevels` a dataframe (please do not mark this question as duplicate :)). 
Given all the methods available only one works. What am I doing wrong?
Example:

```
> df = data.frame(x = (c("a","b","c")),y=c("d","e","f"))
> class(df$x)
[1] "factor"
> levels(df$x)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Method 1 not working:

```
> df1 = droplevels(df)
> class(df1$x)
[1] "factor"
> levels(df1$x)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Method 2 not working:

```
> df2 = as.data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
> class(df2$x)
[1] "factor"
> levels(df2$x)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Method 3 not working:

```
> df3 = df
> df3$x = factor(df3$x) 
> class(df3$x)
[1] "factor"
> levels(df3$x)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Method 4 finally works:

```
> df4 = df
> df4$x = as.vector(df4$x)
> class(df4$x)
[1] "character"
> levels(df4$x)
NULL
```

While working, I think method 4 is the least elegant. Can you help me to debug this? Many thanks

EDIT: Following comments and answers: I want to remove the factor structure from a data frame and not only `droplevels`

Comment: So when you say you want to `droplevels` you really just mean you want to convert the factor variable a character varaible. If so, Method 4 is the only systematically correct choice. `droplevels` removes unobserved levels from a factor, but in your test case, you observe all levels so nothing round be dropped. If you don't want them to be factors in the first place, use `df = data.frame(x = (c("a","b","c")),y=c("d","e","f"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`. Method 2 does not work because they are already factors at that point. What *exactly* is your goal?

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks for explanation, however still strange that method 2 does not work

Comment: @YujiaHu Not strange at all. If you pass `as.data.frame` a data.frame all it does is adjust the class attribute and (possibly) the row names.

Comment: Like I said, Method 2 does not work because `df` already has factors when it was created. The `stringsAsFactors=` parameter only affects character vectors, not vectors that are already factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Dropping levels" refers to getting rid of unused factor levels, but keeping the object as class `factor`. You're looking for a way to convert all factor columns into character columns:

```
> df2 = data.frame(lapply(df, 
           function(x) if (is.factor(x)) as.character(x) else x), 
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> lapply(df2, class)
$x
[1] "character"

$y
[1] "character"

> df2
  x y
1 a d
2 b e
3 c f
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you want:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
```

This has two differences from your code: the "[]" on the LHS of the assignment which preserves the dataframe structure of `df`and the use of `lapply`. The `droplevels` function only drops extraneous levels but does not convert to a character vector.  The `as.character` function does not have a data.frame method. It needs to be (l)-applied to each of the factor vectors rather than to a list of factor vectors. The more general function to do that (avoiding the error of attempting coercion on a numeric vector) would be:

```
 makefac2char <- function(v) if(is.factor(v)){as.character(v)} else {v}
 df[] <- lapply(df, makefac2char)
 # To make a new dataframe
 df2 <- lapply(df, makefac2char)
 df2<- data.frame(df2)
```

If you do not want to destructively replace 'df' then you  need to wrap `data.frame` around the `lapply` results since `lapply` does not maintain attributes. If you had created that dataframe with 'stringAsFactors=FALSE' (or set that option in `.Options`) you would not have needed to do this on a data.frame-wide basis.

Comment: The standard `droplevels()` seems to behave just fine over a data.frame `df = data.frame(x = factor(c("a","b","c"), levels=letters),y=c("d","e","f"), z=1:3); droplevels(df)`. Not sure what this accomplishes.

Comment: Pretty sure `droplevels` does have a data.frame method.

Comment: Sorry. The questioner is confused (and confused me) about what the action of `droplevels`. Edited to give him what he wants, but is using the wrong function to achieve. He wants `as.character`.